# How create Report Sale Order white section

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I want to create report whit section , I have already created a field section in the sales line (see picture).
[[image: field section[1]]

the question is how to create pdf report with the following structure :

[image: structure report]

I have already attacked a solution but is blocking this my solution overriding function order_lines_layouted just display the last section(B3,Section 3)  and inherit report sale order :

```
    @api.multi
def order_lines_layouted(self):
    res  = super(SaleOrder, self).order_lines_layouted()
    """
    Returns this order lines classified by sale_layout_category and separated in
    pages according to the category pagebreaks. Used to render the report.
    """
    self.ensure_one()
    report_pages = [[]]
    for category, lines in groupby(self.order_line, lambda l: l.layout_category_id):
        # If last added category induced a pagebreak, this one will be on a new page
        if report_pages[-1] and report_pages[-1][-1]['pagebreak']:
            report_pages.append([])
        # Append category to current report page
        report_pages[-1].append({
            'name': category and category.name or 'Uncategorized',
            'subtotal': category and category.subtotal,
            'pagebreak': category and category.pagebreak,
            'lines': list(lines)
        })
    print "=========report=========",report_pages[0][0]['name']


    return report_pages
```

QWeb XML inherit :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
    <template id="es_sale_layout" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
            <xpath expr="//tbody[@class='sale_tbody']//tr/td" position="replace">
                <td colspan="7" style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">&amp;bull;
                    <t t-esc="layout_category['name']"/><br/>
                </td>
            </xpath>
    </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

that's the result my solution :
[image]